# Use of if (typeof(obj._source.url) !== 'undefined') expresion in jsontohtml

Tags: javascript, json2html

I am consulting two different json data sources, job1 and job2, with the same code that runs with jsontohtml.

Each source has different labels, although with similar name, some have different name beetween them or different json structure.

I want to detect when a label is defined to show it in html, while if is undefined not show it.

The problem is when I check if the corresponding parameter-object is already defined by next command

```
if (typeof(obj._source.file.url) !== 'undefined')
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

the complete code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>JSON Visualizer</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2html/1.4.0/json2html.min.js"></script>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./tablaX.css">

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="elastic_table">            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

        var trabajo = "job2";
        var url = 'http://localhost:9200/' + trabajo + '/_search'

        let transforms = {  "response":
                        {'<>':'table','class':'table-bordered table-striped table-hover results','html':[

                        {'<>':'thead'},     

                        {'<>':'tr'},
                        {'<>':'th','text':'URL'},


                        {'<>':'tbody'},     

                        {"<>":"div","html":function() {
                                return($.json2html(this.hits.hits,transforms.hitos));
                            }}

                        ]},                 

                        "hitos":{"<>":"tr","html":[

                            {"<>":"td","html":function(obj,index){
                                if (typeof(obj._source.file.url) !== 'undefined') { http = obj._source.file.url.replace("file://", ""); return("<a href='" + http + "'>" + http + "</a>"); };    //job 1 source
                                if (typeof(obj._source.url) !== 'undefined') { http = obj._source.url.replace("file://", ""); return("<a href='" + http + "'>" + http + "</a>"); };      //job 2 source                 

                                }
                                }

                        ]}              

                    };

                    var datos = 
                    {   
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                                 },
                        "size": "10000"
                    }
                    ;               


         [datos].map(function (query) {
          $.ajax({
            url,
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(query),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (responses) {
              console.log({ query, responses });
              $('#elastic_table').html(json2html.transform(responses,transforms.response));
            },
            error: function (err) {
              console.error({ query, err });
            }
          });
        });



        }
    )   
;      

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you comment the code of the following line, which is the one that gives me the error, my jsontohtml code will work without problem

```
if (typeof(obj._source.file.url) !== 'undefined') { http = obj._source.file.url.replace("file://", ""); return("<a href='" + http + "'>" + http + "</a>"); };    //job 1 source
```

The source data of the source job1 is

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "job1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2e2ed07786c01e9fd845b62fb86a693a",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : """hola
""",
          "meta" : { },
          "file" : {
            "extension" : "txt",
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "created" : "2020-04-03T11:57:45.673+0000",
            "last_modified" : "2020-04-23T07:33:50.725+0000",
            "last_accessed" : "2020-04-23T07:33:50.725+0000",
            "indexing_date" : "2020-04-23T10:33:46.954+0000",
            "filesize" : 4,
            "filename" : "fichero0_borrador.txt",
            "url" : """file://C:\TMPM\carpeta0\99.Borrador\fichero0_borrador.txt"""
          },
          "path" : {
            "root" : "4cface21f575d5e5985e4e3889c278a3",
            "virtual" : "PM/carpeta0/99.Borrador/fichero0_borrador.txt",
            "real" : """C:\TMPM\carpeta0\99.Borrador\fichero0_borrador.txt"""
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "job1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6f475ff7ac21fc59f4edc34761d09",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : """cadena0 A
""",
          "meta" : { },
          "file" : {
            "extension" : "txt",
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "created" : "2020-04-14T09:30:20.218+0000",
            "last_modified" : "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
            "last_accessed" : "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
            "indexing_date" : "2020-04-23T10:33:47.533+0000",
            "filesize" : 9,
            "filename" : "fichero0_A.txt",
            "url" : """file://C:\TMPM\carpeta0\fichero0_A.txt"""
          },
          "path" : {
            "root" : "c073f96a8d16ebb2e604bebd4fe8b40",
            "virtual" : "PM/carpeta0/fichero0_A.txt",
            "real" : """C:\TMPM\carpeta0\fichero0_A.txt"""
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "job1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7dfb102f2e64e99740a89b1cff7d92a3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : """cadena1
""",
          "meta" : { },
          "file" : {
            "extension" : "txt",
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "created" : "2020-04-03T11:56:21.165+0000",
            "last_modified" : "2020-04-03T12:23:23.872+0000",
            "last_accessed" : "2020-04-03T12:23:23.872+0000",
            "indexing_date" : "2020-04-23T10:33:47.568+0000",
            "filesize" : 7,
            "filename" : "fichero1.txt",
            "url" : """file://C:\TMPM\carpeta1\fichero1.txt"""
          },
          "path" : {
            "root" : "7ff4e7b0e0c3172dbd29a23861ab2125",
            "virtual" : "PM/carpeta1/fichero1.txt",
            "real" : """C:\TMPM\carpeta1\fichero1.txt"""
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "job1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "74f0e8c1cccf2f32b4d43673cfdca0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : """cadena2
""",
          "meta" : { },
          "file" : {
            "extension" : "txt",
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "created" : "2020-04-03T11:56:30.524+0000",
            "last_modified" : "2020-04-03T12:23:35.029+0000",
            "last_accessed" : "2020-04-03T12:23:35.029+0000",
            "indexing_date" : "2020-04-23T10:33:47.579+0000",
            "filesize" : 7,
            "filename" : "fichero2.txt",
            "url" : """file://C:\TMPM\carpeta2\fichero2.txt"""
          },
          "path" : {
            "root" : "fd0c8ae8a885725cfcaee774c72be43",
            "virtual" : "PM/carpeta2/fichero2.txt",
            "real" : """C:\TMPM\carpeta2\fichero2.txt"""
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "job1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8d6c56c0448bc4bfa17787923baa9c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : """cadenaX
""",
          "meta" : { },
          "file" : {
            "extension" : "txt",
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "created" : "2020-04-14T15:12:56.632+0000",
            "last_modified" : "2020-04-14T15:34:53.139+0000",
            "last_accessed" : "2020-04-14T15:34:53.139+0000",
            "indexing_date" : "2020-04-23T10:33:47.587+0000",
            "filesize" : 7,
            "filename" : "fichero_X.txt",
            "url" : """file://C:\TMPM\carpetaX\fichero_X.txt"""
          },
          "path" : {
            "root" : "f43118a935c6c7ef81ea65307759fc",
            "virtual" : "PM/carpetaX/fichero_X.txt",
            "real" : """C:\TMPM\carpetaX\fichero_X.txt"""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One, `typeof` is not a function, so `typeof something` instead of `typeof(something)`. Two, it's telling you `file` is undefined here: `obj._source.file` You can't get a property from undefined.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error `file` is undefined in `obj._source.file.url`. Try

```
if (typeof obj._source.file !== 'undefined') { 
    if (typeof obj._source.file.url !== 'undefined') {
        http = obj._source.file.url.replace("file://", ""); return("<a href='" + http + "'>" + http + "</a>"); 
    };
};    //job 1 source
```

Comment: From there you should be able to verify with a simple else statement and go from there.

Comment: `if (obj && obj._source && obj._source.file && obj._source.file.url) {...}`

Comment: Also I tested typeof() at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof and it works with the parenthesis. Bad practice, but that's not your pressing issue.

Comment: It's not bad practice, it's an odd practice. Consider that none of the following is actually "wrong" per se: `(a => { return(a &&(true &&(10 &&(false))) ||(typeof(1.444) === 'float' ))})(1)` The parans are grouping expressions, so they're legal, but unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The code that I added was one of many tests that I have done, in which I left the famous incorrect parentheses. I'm aware that I am going to find my object `obj._source.file` in an undeclared and undefined state. Precisely because the json it will receive will change its definition and structure (it is a mix of several jsons). And precisely because of that, I used `typeof obj._source.file! == 'undefined'` as Google replied *“Use the typeof operator: If you want to check whether a variable has been initialized or defined (ie test whether a variable has been declared and assigned a value) you can use the typeof operator."*

Finally I used

```
 if (obj && obj._source && obj._source.file && obj._source.file.url) {...}
```

by Jared Farrish with good result. Thank you